# Get percentage specific data grouping foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql

Table name: products

product_id        name

1                       test1

2                       test2

3                       test3

Table name: product_type

product_type_id        product_fk        type_name         type_percentage

1                                
1                       
nylon               
50

2                                
1                       
cotton               
50

3                                
2                       
cotton               
50

4                                
2                       
poly                 
50

5                                
3                       
cotton               
50

6                                
3                       
silk                    
50

I need to get products having type cotton 50% and nylon 50%, so the result would be: 

product_id        name 

1                       test1

Please help! 
thanks!

Comment: So as far as I understood a product can be of multiple types? A thing you should consider here is that the database is not designed properly. Because any product can be of multiple product types and any product type can be a part of multiple products you have a many-to-many relationship. Those are resolved using a junction table. I'd suggest, if possible, normalizing your database before continuing.

Comment: @Alternatex Understood, thanks for the suggestion, I thought about the same thing. Unfortunately I'm working on an existing project and updating the structure will require major changes in programming side, so for now need a temporary urgent fix. But planning to revamp soon, so any suggestions would greatly help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.

One way is by joining the products table to the product_type table multiple times:

```
select p.product_id,p.name 
from products p 
  inner join product_type pt1 on pt1.product_fk = p.product_id 
  inner join product_type pt2 on pt2.product_fk = p.product_id 
where pt1.type_name = 'cotton'
  and pt1.type_percentage = 50
  and pt2.type_name = 'nylon'
  and pt2.type_percentage = 50
```

Another option is to use `EXISTS`:

```
select p.product_id,p.name 
from products p 
where exists (
  select null 
  from product_type pt1 
  where pt1.product_fk = p.product_id 
    and pt1.type_name = 'cotton' 
    and pt1.type_percentage = 50
)
and exists (
  select null 
  from product_type pt2 
  where pt2.product_fk = p.product_id 
    and pt2.type_name = 'nylon' 
    and pt2.type_percentage = 50
)
```

Comment: Thanks! This is perfect, you saved me a lot of time.